# Add loop to vba code for excel

Tags: loops, excel, vba

I know little about vba so I am hoping someone can help me.

I have the following code below, it "fill blank cells in column with value above" and works fine.

I need to use it on NON-contiguous coloumns.
Is there a way to add a loop to it so that it will run on [B D H I] columns?

I have tryed to puzzel this out have not got anywhere

Thanks

```
Sub FillColBlanks()
'by Dave Peterson  2004-01-06
'fill blank cells in column with value above
'http://www.contextures.com/xlDataEntry02.html
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range 
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim col As Long

Set wks = ActiveSheet
With wks
   'col = ActiveCell.Column
   'or
   col = .Range("G2").Column

   Set rng = .UsedRange  'try to reset the lastcell
   Lastrow = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
   Set rng = Nothing
   On Error Resume Next
   Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, col), .Cells(Lastrow, col)) _
                  .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
   On Error GoTo 0

   If rng Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox "No blanks found"
       Exit Sub
   Else
       rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
   End If

   'replace formulas with values
   With .Cells(1, col).EntireColumn
       .Value = .Value
   End With

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try the below:

```
Sub FillColBlanks(sColRange as string)

'by Dave Peterson  2004-01-06
'fill blank cells in column with value above
'http://www.contextures.com/xlDataEntry02.html
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range 
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim col As Long

Set wks = ActiveSheet
With wks
   'col = ActiveCell.Column
   'or
   col = .Range(sColRange).Column

   Set rng = .UsedRange  'try to reset the lastcell
   Lastrow = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
   Set rng = Nothing
   On Error Resume Next
   Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, col), .Cells(Lastrow, col)) _
                  .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
   On Error GoTo 0

   If rng Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox "No blanks found"
       Exit Sub
   Else
       rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
   End If

   'replace formulas with values
   With .Cells(1, col).EntireColumn
       .Value = .Value
   End With

End With

End Sub
```

so you call that procedure like this:

```
Call FillColBlanks("B1")
Call FillColBlanks("D1")
Call FillColBlanks("H1")
Call FillColBlanks("I1")
```

Comment: + 1 Well if you hide the all the columns except B,D,H,I then you can consider them as one range? This would prevent you from calling `FillColBlanks` again and again? Just a thought...