# How to call code for multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I need to run the following code on non-contiguous columns, There is code posted here on how to do this for a different piece of code.
[Add loop to vba code for excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238951/add-loop-to-vba-code-for-excel)

I Need to do the same for:

```
Sub CleanAll()
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D100").Cells 'adjust sheetname and range   accordingly
        rng.Value = TextOnly(rng.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

My failed effort

```
Sub CleanAll(sColRange As String)
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range(sColRange).Cells 'adjust sheetname and range accordingly
        rng.Value = TextOnly(rng.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

use like this:

```
Call CleanAll("B2")
Call CleanAll("H2")
```

Thanks

Edit

The above calls the following

```
Function TextOnly(strSource As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strResult As String

    For i = 1 To Len(strSource)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strSource, i, 1))
            Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122: 'include 32 if you want to include space
                strResult = strResult & Mid(strSource, i, 1)
        End Select
    Next
    AlphaNumericOnly = strResult
End Function
```

Comment: What's the problem? Your edited version seems like it should work, so maybe it's how you're calling it?  Maybe you should try something like `CleanAll "B2,H2"`

Comment: This works fine the way you are doing it, what's your actual code which isn't working? What is `TextOnly`?

Comment: Yes, from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723672/how-to-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-period-and-sp

Comment: The apparent problem is that `TextOnly` is not defined anywhere.  In your subroutine called `CleanAll()` you are calling a function named `TextOnly`. Yet you are providing a function called `AlphaNumericOnly`.  Does it work, if you revise it to call the proper `AlphaNumericOnly` function?

Comment: Sorry about that I revised my code, still does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't simple pass range to subroutine?

```
Sub CleanAll(range as Range)
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In range.Cells 
        rng.Value = TextOnly(rng.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

then you can call it by

```
CleanAll(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100"))
```